# assembly convert number into character

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I have this variable:

```
Message DB 10 dup(?)
```

I'm trying to generate 10 random characters and then save them into variable.

```
mov ecx,10
mov edi,0

GenerateString:
    mov eax,60h
    call RandomRange
    sub eax,27
    add al,'0'
    mov Message[edi],al

    inc edi
    loop GenerateString

mov edx,offset Message
call WriteString
```

I found somewhere that I have to substract number by 27 and add ascii 0, but it's not working properly. Please note I have to use RandomRange.

Comment: The question can't be answered because you haven't specified the range of characters that you want to generate.

Comment: The range doesn't matter. It's not that hard to edit it after. It would be enough for a-z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irvine's [`RandomRange`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Frandomrange.htm) creates numbers in the range 0..EAX-1. With other words: You get a number within a range of a certain amount of different numbers. Since you want an ASCII character in the range a..z (97..122) you have

- to determine the size of the range: 122-97+1 = 26 characters,
- to move the
  range of [`RandomRange`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Frandomrange.htm) to the desired range by adding the start
  value: 97.

BTW: You will always get the same sequence if you don't initialize [`RandomRange`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Frandomrange.htm) with [`Randomize`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Frandomize.htm).

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
    Message DB 10 dup(0)

.CODE
main PROC

    call Randomize                      ; Initialization for `RandomRange`

    mov ecx, LENGTHOF Message - 1       ; Without the terminating null!
    mov edi, 0

    GenerateString:

    mov eax, 26                         ; Range: [0..25] = 26 numbers
    call RandomRange
    add eax, 97                         ; Move the range from [0..25] to [97..122]
    mov Message[edi],al

    inc edi
    loop GenerateString

    mov edx,offset Message
    call WriteString

    exit

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: thanks for explanation :) I was wondering why I always had same result